# In Apache thrift, is there a safe way to send a call while another one is still in progress?

Tags: thrift

Let's say I have two thrift RPC method: `FirstMethod` and `SecondMethod`. In one thread, I call `FirstMethod()`. Is there a safe way to call `SecondMethod` in another thread with the same thrift connection before `FirstMethod()` finished?

```
    public List<Record> FirstMethod()
    {
        // thrift call may take more than 10 second
    }

    public bool SecondMethod(string callUid)
    {
        // thrift call
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, instances of the Thrift transport/protocol stack cannot be used across threads. IOW, clients are bound to the creating thread.

But having two clients (each for one thread) doing calls against the same server is of course possible.